# Is there a utility to find artefacts within an media stream?

Tags: debian, video

I was running a media video file under .mpv . After approx. half the movie there was a jump from where it was and went to the end. Is there a utility to asess the health of a media file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ffprobe gathers information from multimedia streams and prints it in
>   human- and machine-readable fashion.
>
> For example it can be used to check the format of the container
>   used by a multimedia stream and the    format and type of each media
>   stream contained in it.

```
ffprobe -show_error test.mpv
```

Example output (part):

```
Input #0, mpeg, from 'test-mpeg.mpg':
  Duration: 00:00:21.00, start: 0.768300, bitrate: 269 kb/s
    Stream #0:0[0x1e0]: Video: mpeg1video, yuv420p(tv), 160x120 [SAR 1:1 DAR 4:3], 104857 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 30 tbc
    Stream #0:1[0x1c0]: Audio: mp2, 32000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 64 kb/s
```

You may want to check the duration.

A more thorough method is to transcode the mpv to null/nothing. Each frame will only be read from the sourcefile and only errors will be printed (see last line). No output indicates that the file is ok. This will take longer than ffprobe.

```
ffmpeg -v error -i test.mpv -f null -
```

Example for an error:

```
[mpeg1video @ 0x55ddfc052fe0] ac-tex damaged at 2 0
[mpeg1video @ 0x55ddfc052fe0] Warning MVs not available
```